# Migrating Db to new server

Tags: mysql

Some questions, if I may....
[updated to clarify for commentors.]

Looking in phpMyAdmin the total size of my tables is said to be 174MiB.

(I saw this when I selected the db in left col and, in the table in the right col, theres a tableCol called size. last record shows total being 173.9MiB)

When I make a .sql backup, it's 2.5Gb

I backed up like this on command line:
mysqldump -u root -p --opt [database name] > [database name].sql

1. Why the difference?  Is phpMyAdmin wrong or are there other files generated as part of the backup.
2. will that .sql file contain everything for a properly duplicated Db, including constraints and indexes?
3. current db is described as MySQL and on new server its MySQL MariaDB.  Will the MariaDB support a .sql file made with 'plain' MySQL?

Comment: how do you know that it is only 174, second, your backup file has a lot of text, when you look into it. last as we don't know what parameters you used, so try the back up in a vm at home

Comment: 'Will the MariaDB support a .sql file made with 'plain' MySQL?' - not necessarily you could trip up on visible indexes for example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Phpmyadmin exports everything as text, while mysql stores numbers as dates as numbers. Also, phpmyadmin export may contain full sql statements making the file even bigger.
2. This depends on how you configured phpmyadmin's export process. You can check the result file with text editors that can handle large data.
3. Mariadb is **not** mysql, it is a **fork**. This means that they are very similar, but not the same. You need to check mariadb's documentation on [compatibility and differences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compatibility-differences/) and make your manual adjustments to your backup, otherwise you may encounter errors when you try to restore the mysql backup to a mariadb server.

Comment: Thank you. To create the sql file I used the command line code:  mysqldump -u root -p --opt [database name] > [database name].sql  Might that chnage what you wrote for Q2? looks like Maria takes sundays off. lol (site not accessible for me currently.)

Comment: You can check mysqldump documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) or check the generated file.